binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (41) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
I'm trying to use py-vapid, pywebpush, and django-push-notifications to send notifications via Webpush. When I try to send a test notification from the django admin website, I get this traceback log in the console:
      | Internal Server Error: /djangoadmin/push_notifications/webpushdevice/
      | Traceback (most recent call last):
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 518, in thread_handler
      |     raise exc_info[1]
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 38, in inner
      |     response = await get_response(request)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 233, in _get_response_async
      |     response = await wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 468, in __call__
      |     ret = await asyncio.shield(exec_coro)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/current_thread_executor.py", line 40, in run
      |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 522, in thread_handler
      |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
      |     return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
      |     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
      |     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
      |     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
      |     return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
      |     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1723, in changelist_view
      |     response = self.response_action(request, queryset=cl.get_queryset(request))
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1408, in response_action
      |     response = func(self, request, queryset)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/push_notifications/admin.py", line 109, in send_message
      |     self.send_messages(request, queryset)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/push_notifications/admin.py", line 38, in send_messages
      |     r = device.send_message("Test single notification")
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/push_notifications/models.py", line 270, in send_message
      |     return webpush_send_message(self, message, **kwargs)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/push_notifications/webpush.py", line 35, in webpush_send_message
      |     response = webpush(
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pywebpush/__init__.py", line 560, in webpush
      |     vv = Vapid.from_string(private_key=vapid_private_key)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py_vapid/__init__.py", line 144, in from_string
      |     key = b64urldecode(pkey)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py_vapid/utils.py", line 14, in b64urldecode
      |     return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(data + b"===="[len(data) % 4:])
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
      |     return b64decode(s)
      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
      |     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
      | binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (41) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

It seems like its saying my keys aren't in a valid format to be converted to Base64, but I checked pywebpush's docs and my keys are in the correct VAPID EC2 private key PEM file format. They were generated with py-vapid like so:
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, PrivateFormat, NoEncryption, PublicFormat
from py_vapid import Vapid
import base64

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Generate VAPID key pair
vapid = Vapid()
vapid.generate_keys()

# Get public and private keys for the vapid key pair
vapid.save_public_key(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "keys", "webpush", "public_key.pem"))
public_key_bytes = vapid.public_key.public_bytes(Encoding.X962, PublicFormat.UncompressedPoint)

vapid.save_key(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "keys", "webpush", "private_key.pem"))


# Convert the public key to applicationServerKey format
application_server_key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(public_key_bytes).replace(b'=', b'').decode('utf8')

with open(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "keys", "webpush", "ApplicationServerKey.key"), "w") as f:
    f.write(application_server_key)

Here are the test keys in question:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgFCZ0WxsNENwKK3Pf
c0HFZPDlr/KAmjIwB6Hz/OdH/YKhRANCAASFpOW98Q4xfCjD0Taog9ZstRQgS+Ch
L7HoOBGHFZAQwpEd83Qt58bnUCIZFwMZc4tyHKV+b0UxM2cMzm8pMI4z
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----


-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEhaTlvfEOMXwow9E2qIPWbLUUIEvg
oS+x6DgRhxWQEMKRHfN0LefG51AiGRcDGXOLchylfm9FMTNnDM5vKTCOMw==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----


I've tried to generate keys manually using OpenSSL but it still won't work.
